# C# - Static initializer is not called when field is accessed from other class' static constructor

Tags: c#

I have the following struct

```cs
public struct RenderLayer : IComparable<RenderLayer>, IEqualityComparer<RenderLayer> {

    public static readonly RenderLayer Default = new(nameof(Default), RenderLayerManager.NextLayerId);
    
    public readonly string name;
    public readonly int id;
    
    public RenderLayer (string name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
        Log.Notice("Render layer constructor");
    }

    public int CompareTo (RenderLayer other) => id.CompareTo(other.id);

    public bool Equals (RenderLayer x, RenderLayer y) {
        return x.id == y.id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode (RenderLayer obj) {
        return obj.id;
    }

}
```

And a manager class that holds all RenderLayers (the default one added here + others added from user configuration)

```cs
public static class RenderLayerManager {

    public static int NextLayerId => nextLayerId++;
    
    private static int nextLayerId = 0;
    private static readonly List<RenderLayer> layers = new();

    static RenderLayerManager () {
        Log.Notice("Render layer manager constructor, before");
        layers.Add(RenderLayer.Default);
        Log.Notice("Render layer manager constructor, after");
    }

    public static Span<RenderLayer> Layers => CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(layers);

}
```

The problem is when the Layers property is used it somehow contains one RenderLayer that is not initialized. The output of the Log.Notice calls is:

```
[Notice] Render layer manager constructor, before
[Notice] Render layer manager constructor, after
[Notice] Render layer constructor
```

As far as I understand static initialization the static field in RenderLayer should be initialized when it is first accessed (or before). But clearly it is being initialized after the RenderLayerManager's constructor is completed

Edit:
I've made an example for it. At first it seemed to also have the error but now I can't reproduce it. I have no idea why my project still has this issue but this example is running as expected. https://dotnetfiddle.net/P4FJ7Q

Comment: Works as expected for me in .Net 7. Feel free to provide an example project we can actually compile and run that exhibits the problem. That said, you wouldn't be in this mess if you followed basic programming principles, like not to use static or singletons (even actually properly written with read-only properties) in the first place. There's absolutely no reason for it.

Comment: This output ought not the be possible, assuming `Log` logs sequentially -- `RenderLayer` could be initialized before the static `RenderLayerManager` constructor runs, but not after. Indeed, I can't repro this using either .NET 4.x or 6.x (and using `Console.WriteLine` insteadf of `Log.Notice`), though that's with both types in the same assembly. Out of interest, does the output change if you add `static RenderLayer() {}` (thereby forcing the removal of `beforefieldinit`)?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I should get in a habbit of creating minimal reproductions. Thanks for mentioning it. The problem indeed does not occur when I create a new project with just these 2 classes inside.

@JeroenMostert `Log` is just a thin wrapper around Console.WriteLine. I tried adding a static constructor to `RenderLayer` but that didn't change anything. I have no idea why it ends up initializing the `RenderLayer` last.

@Blindy To be honest, I don't really know what the best way would be to do this. It's just a solo game project so I felt this was a nice simple solution.

Comment: Try creating a [mcve] at https://dotnetfiddle.net

Comment: @JeroenMostert: *If* RenderLayer begins its static initialization first, then it begins executing `Default = new()`, which in turns tries to execute `RenderLayerManager.NextId` before entering into the `RenderLayer` ctor, accessing `RenderLayerManager.NextId` triggers static initialization of `RenderLayerManager`, which then prints out `before/after`, then it returns to `RenderLayer` ctor with the result of `NextId` and the `RenderLayer` ctor prints out the third log line. Everything fits perfectly the presented log dump. So why should this be impossible?

Comment: @quetzalcoatl That is it! When I use `RenderLayer.Default` before `RenderLayerManager.Layers` is accessed the issue happens in the DotNetFiddle too. It does make sense then since RenderLayer is not going to recursively be initialized again before the constructor is done. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Blindy meant was many things. Avoiding mutable static state, avoiding singletons, avoiding depending on order of static initialization -- these are one of the basic rules (*) of not insisting on making your life harder that in must be. In the code you presented, you "break" all of those three "rules", and, unsurprisingly, static initialization order somehow has biten you.

(*) that's not a complete list; some consider these to be "rules", some consider them "advices" or "guidelines", some consider that "code style", other say it's "antipattern".. it's in the language, compiler allows that, so it's not forbidden, but then, so are `unsafe` native pointers also available in C# :)

What you deduced from the log is wrong. RenderLayer is not "clearly it is being initialized after the RenderLayerManager's constructor is completed".

In fact, the log you provided proves, that it was FIRST to be executed. But not first to complete.

Look at this line, how does it execute? Precisely, please?

```
(..) readonly RenderLayer Default = new("blah", RenderLayerManager.NextLayerId);
```

It calls into `RenderLayer` constructor, but that's not all. It also passes parameters. And to be able to call the constructor, it HAS TO have the parameters' values' already computed. Then, how is the second parameter computed?

This means, that what has happened in your code was:

- compiler picked RenderLayout as the first to be initialized statically, for some reason
- `RenderLayout` initialization has started
- it tried to initialize first static field: `Default`
- it started preparing parameters' values' for constructor
- doing so, it tries to read `RenderLayerManager` class static property
- `RenderLayerManager` was detected by CLR to not have been initialized yet
- CLR tries to fix the problem in flight: upon `.NextId` being accessed, CLR begins static init of `RenderLayerManager`
- `RenderLayerManager` initialization has started
- `RenderLayerManager` static `nextLayerId` is set to 0 (not really, but let's say it is..)
- `RenderLayerManager` static `layers` is initialized - `List` is created, its ctor is called, then `layers` is set to that new list instance
- all fields inited, so `RenderLayerManager` static ctor is called
- RLM's static ctor writes out BEGIN log line
- RLM's static ctor executes `layers.add`, or rather, wants
- RLM's static ctor prepares parameters for `layers.add` - accesses `RenderLayer.Default`
- `RenderLayer` is not initialized yet - but it is UNDER INITIALIZATION - so it's static initialization procedure IS NOT CALLED AGAIN
- `RenderLayer.Default` is read out and contains trash, I'd expect `null` here since CLR zeroes all memory (I think it's mostly guaranteed to be zeroed out, except for certain COM interop and P/Invoke cases)
- RLM's static ctor writes out END log line
- static ctor of `RenderLayerManager` ends
- execution returns where it was, static init of `RenderLayer` continues preparing args for `new()` in `RenderLayer`
- `RenderLayerManager.NextId` is read (and getter executes, increments counter, etc)
- all parameters for `new()` are now ready
- `RenderLayer` ctor is called, does its thing, writes out third log line

The thing with static initialization is this - it is hard to trace. Tiny things can force picking different starting point than you'd expect. Things can be pulled and executed in the middle if they are needed. When things are under ongoing initialization, they are not guaranteed to be coherent, and so on. That's why it's best to avoid it as much as possible and instead rely on things easier to plan out.

Let's drop the argument about not using static, and not using singletons, that's an independent discussion. Let's focus on static initialization. Why do you use it?

Maybe you wanted to have it "lazy" - if "RenderLayer" AND "RenderLayerManager" were not used, they'd be not initalized. Maybe you wanted to have it surely initialized before setting up before everything else. Or some other reason. I don't know. But at least for those two things, there are other ways.

- for lazy initialization, on first access, there's the `Lazy<T>` class that does exactly this
- for "before everything else" you can just use the good old main(). Why rely on static initialization order to be able to guess what you wanted, when you can just have it just like you have it now, and just conceptually move the `RL.Default = new(..)` and `RLM.layers.add(RL.Default)` to `main()` before you run the game loop? You don't have to paste that code there, just wrap these pieces in methods and then in `main()` you can just write `RLM.Initialize(); RL.Initialize();` or something like that, and you will instantly see why the static initialization order is important and sometimes ends up in a chicken-and-egg problem you have here (chicken: RLM.Initialize wants to use RL.Default, egg: RL.Initialize creates Default, but needs RLM.NextId).

*Notabene: Compiler NEVER will solve any chicken-and-egg probems for you. Sometimes, it can point out them to you, like when trying to make `struct A` have field of `struct B` and also make B have a field of A. But that's a lucky case. Often, compiler will not notice chicken-and-egg problems, because not all of them make compilation impossible, and sometimes their effect simply manifests only at runtime, when the compiler is on its well-earned holidays already - like in your case.*

Then, solve the chicken and egg problem. For example, like this:

```
public static int Main()
{
    // lets be 'sure' that RLM is first to be init'ed
    RenderLayerManager.Initialize();
}

public struct RenderLayer : ...
{ 
    public static readonly RenderLayer Default;

    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Default = new(nameof(Default), RenderLayerManager.NextLayerId);
    }
    
    ...
    
    public RenderLayer (string name, int id) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}

public static class RenderLayerManager {
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        RenderLayer.Initialize();
        layers.Add(RenderLayer.Default);
    }
    
    ...

    static RenderLayerManager () {
        Log.Notice("Render layer manager constructor, before");
        // layers.Add(RenderLayer.Default); // ***
        Log.Notice("Render layer manager constructor, after");
    }

    ...
}
```

Note that leaving layers.add at the old place would probably be fine now, since RLM begins initializing first, and then would pull RL, but that would happen only after RLM's field init is completed - so counter would be already ready - but - really - we want to minimize dependency on static initialization order, and that's why I move it now to `RLM.Initialize()`, so any reader of this code has no problem in determinig what precedes and what follows.

Key points of my proposed changes (if I not botched something, and I CERTAINLY COULD, because I write it all here, and I have not tried compiling or testing it all):

- static init of RL does not touch RLM
- static init of RLM does not touch RL
- RL and RLM expose `Initialize` methods that do final required steps, all those that must touch the other class
- SOMEONE is responsible for calling those `Initialize` methods IN CORRECT ORDER
- just as an example, I chained one Initialize within another, and rooted the chain in the Main() -- but that can be made differently, just have it all plain in sight, and easy to trace

Comment: I see. My intent to write it in a simple way that I could use without further setup was actually naive and causing issues. Thank you for writing it all out! Your code does make it clear what is happening instead of relying on assumptions. This makes it usable for now, I will have to look into better ways to handle this sort of configuration